# LD_PRELOAD variable in JNI code

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, ld-preload

My java code calls via JNI some C++ code from a shared library (eg libtest.so). The code is instrumented with some special debugging symbols that exist it libdebug.so. When I call

> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libdebug.so java com.test.myMain

the execution stops with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`

because symbols from libdebug.so are not loaded (why?).

I was wondering if it is possible to modify my code in order to PRELOAD the library inside my java code. (Of course I don't want to compile java with libdebug.so...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.load`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load%28java.lang.String%29) can be used to load any shared library, so you might try loading the debug library in a static block using `System.load` (before you load your JNI lib). 
Or try `System.loadLibary("debug")` before your JNI lib.

Comment: How do I load multiple libraries? Can I do it with one command, or do I need multiple?

Comment: You will need multiple calls to `load` AFAIK.